# Opencart: How to render a template only on a specific page?

Tags: opencart

In my `catalog/controller/mycontroller.php`, I have a script like this:

```
$this->data['settings'] = $this->config->get('my_module');  // retrieves data from "setting" table
foreach ($this->data['settings'] as $data) {
    if ($data['pageurl'] == 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
        $this->render();
    }
}
```

In `Extensions > Modules`, I have my extension installed where I can set different page URLs to different `Layouts` and `Positions` like this:

```
Page URL                   Layout    Position
================================================
http://...?product_id=10   Product   Content Top
http://...?product_id=20   Product   Content Top
http://...                 Home      Content Top
```

My issue is - I'd like to render a template only ONCE on a specific page that meets the condition in the above script. What's currently happening is `$this->render()` is showing the template MULTIPLE times based on the `Position` and `Layout` in `Extensions > Modules`. For instance, when I visit `http://...?product_id=10` page, it displays the template twice while it's only supposed to display it once because it only meets the condition for `product_id=10` in the controller. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do this:

```
var_dump('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

I guess You may be missing also the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` part...

to see, what URL are You building to compare to URLs You are setting in the backend...

Next, please, do not call `$this->render()` in a loop no matter why the condition succeed more times, instead of this do something like this:

```
$this->data['settings'] = $this->config->get('my_module');  // retrieves data from "setting" table
$render = false;
foreach ($this->data['settings'] as $data) {
    if ($data['pageurl'] == HTTP_SERVER . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) { // use defined constant HTTP_SERVER
        $render = true;
    }
}

if($render) {
    $this->render();
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: So what's happening is it's going through `catalog\controller\common\content_top.php` twice because the `Product` layout is assigned to `Content Top` twice.